# Ubuntu 20.04 Software Updater failed

Tags: update-manager

I have Ubuntu 20.04, 64 bit, Kernel Linux 5.11.0-18-generic x86_64,MATE 1.24.1.
Software Updater pop up daily, gets my OK, but informs "package operation failed".
I tried to back it up by:
<sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade>
Can that help? Hopefully you have a batter idea. Thanks.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is still currently at 20.04.2 and using the 5.8 kernel, are you using Ubuntu? as why do you report the proposed 5.11?   (if you're using proposed or *testing* software issues are more likely and should be reported via bug tracker)

Comment: Thank you. No reason to doubt what you say. But what I reported was copied from "About this computer information" and the result of very recent "update & upgrade." Will try to do that again... Done. Returned as, "Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)".

Comment: Please post full complete error output from the terminal for `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade `. We can't help you without this information.

Comment: <FATAL ERROR:
< /bin/usb_printerid and /usr/bin/usb_printerid exist.
<dpkg: error processing package usrmerge (--configure): installed usrmerge package post-<installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
<newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: igor-
<dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
<installed postfix package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 75
<Errors were encountered while processing:
<usrmerge
<postfix
<E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: NOrbert: Sorry. I couldn't fully quote all answer of Terminal. It's not accepted here as "too long." What I presented is a part of that, which has words "error". Is it what you asked for? Because to me it's but a strange language. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Additional detail (ie. pastes) should be added to your question. You have the rights to edit your own questions; plus greater formatting is available for Questions/Answers allowing it to be easily readable, thus increasing your chance of meaningful & correct advice.

Comment: sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
[sudo] password for igor: 
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                  
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease [109 kB] 
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [101 kB]
Hit:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Get:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main i386 Packages [92.3 kB]
Get:7 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/main amd64

Comment: Get:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe amd64 Packages [215 kB]
Get:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates/universe i386 Packages [184 kB]
Fetched 870 kB in 1s (613 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... DoneW: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main'/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

Comment: W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main'/binary-amd64/Packages', as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main'/i18n/Translation-en', as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

Comment: W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main'/i18n/Translation-en', as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main'/i18n/Translation-en_GB', as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

Comment: W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main'/dep11/Components-amd64.yml', as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main'/dep11/icons-48x48.tar', as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

Comment: W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main'/dep11/icons-64x64.tar', as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'main'/cnf/Commands-amd64', as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up usrmerge (24ubuntu3) ...

Comment: FATAL ERROR:
Both /bin/usb_printerid and /usr/bin/usb_printerid exist.

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

dpkg: error processing package usrmerge (--configure):
 installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up postfix (3.5.6-1) ...

Comment: Postfix (main.cf) configuration was not changed.  If you need to make changes, 
edit /etc/postfix/main.cf (and others) as needed.  To view Postfix 
configuration values, see postconf(1).

After modifying main.cf, be sure to run 'systemctl reload postfix'.

Running newaliases
newaliases: warning: valid_hostname: misplaced delimiter: igor-System-Product-Name..
newaliases: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter myhostname: bad parameter value: igor-System-Product-Name..

Comment: dpkg: error processing package postfix (--configure):
 installed postfix package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 75
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.33-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 usrmerge
 postfix
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Please add additional details to your question, and not via comment.  Greater formatting is possible in questions/answers that is allowed in comments; and comments are extremely hard to read when pasted detail.  Also your pasted detail appears to be 21.04 or *hirsute* and not 20.04 or *focal*.  ie. your pasted detail does **not** match your question (but does explain the *hirsute* kernel I queried)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if what I provided did not help. The "questions/answers" was already mentioned above. Where is it? I could not find. Would it not be easier for me to reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: The question refers to your original question (ie. there is an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1340957/edit) link.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer on https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-boot-repair.
Right now, my Software Updater works just fine and Terminal shows no issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was caused by the Microsoft ODBC driver package. On installation, it needs you to confirm the licence agreement and this doesn't work in the Software Updater.
To get around it, from the terminal,run:

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

The second command will then require you to confirm the licence agreement and once done, everything will work as normal.